# Overriding twig blocks: the content of the overriden block is rendered as part of the document also

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm reading [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-1-inside-the-same-template-as-the-form) section about forms customization.

Now I want to custom a widget by myself so I have written the code below to overwrite the `{% block money_widget %}`. It works ok, but the content of my new block is also shown as you can see in the image. Why?

```
{% use 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block money_widget %}
here my the content of the block
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{{ form(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

This is the form type:

```
    $builder
        ->add('user', null, array('label' => 'Cliente'))
        ->add('numberPlate', null, array('label' => 'Número matrícula', 'data' => 'prueba'))
        ->add('subtotal', MoneyType::class)
        ->add('tax', MoneyType::class, array('label' => 'I.V.A.'))
        ->add('total', MoneyType::class, array('label' => 'Total'))
        ->add('Guardar', SubmitType::class)
    ;
```

**EDIT:** I've found when this "problem" exactly happens: when the block to override the widget *is inside template that is is being included using [`include`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html)*. But why? Anyway, for this not to happen, I've created a template that works as a form theme, and add it this way for example:

`{% form_theme form 'here_is_the_block_to_override_the_widget.html.twig' %}`

in the template that I'm including using `include`

Comment: I made the same steps as you, and I don't have any troubles. Please provide also Controller code

Comment: @DenisAlimov Ok, I think I will rewrite my question tomorrow with another example.

Comment: @DenisAlimov I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

original widget in form_div_layout:

```
{%- block money_widget -%}
    {{ money_pattern|replace({ '{{ widget }}': block('form_widget_simple') })|raw }}
{%- endblock money_widget -%}
```

your block:

```
{% block money_widget %}
    here my the content of the block
{% endblock %}
```

When you override the original block in your own template, the block from your template will be shown whenever money widget needs to be rendered. So in your final page you see *here my the content of the block*, as expected. BTW, in your tutorial page there is no `use` statement, maybe that makes it confusing.

Comment: thanks, but I don't exactly know what should I do. Maybe my english is not perfect.. At the beginning I have thought I have to add the hyphens, but "here my the content of the block" is still there at the top..

Comment: Does your form contain MoneyType? Better yet, paste your FormType class into the question and tell what exactly you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Because your template must extend a `base` template referencing `block content`.

Create a minimal base template in `app/Ressources/views/base.html.twig` with :

```
{% block content %}                
{% endblock content %}
```

and extends it in your template like this:

```
{% extends '::baseEmail.html.twig' %}
{% use 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block money_widget %}
    here my the content of the block
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {{ form(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```